# Can I replace s standard DOM functions like removeChild?

Tags: javascript

Can I replace s standard DOM functions like removeChild to show for example alert before some node removed from parent? Something like that but my example is with errors

```
var original = node.removeChild;
node.removeChild = function(node, original){
    alert('message');
    original(node);
}
```

Comment: You could, but you shound not.

Comment: @kan Why not? Without knowing the context, you can't say "You should not".

Comment: @alex23 Please do not apply such significant changes to the code of questions/answers. The (non-)existence of the `new` keyword is significant. It could only confuse the author (and they won't learn anything about it, because you just changed the code without comment)

Comment: you may want to change the `Node.prototype.removeChild`, if you want to apply this across the document rather than for a single node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply this across the document do this

```
var original = Node.prototype.removeChild;
Node.prototype.removeChild = function(node) {
    //custom logic
    original.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

If you want to apply the change only to a selected node then

```
var original = node.removeChild;
node.removeChild = function(node){
    //custom logic
    original.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: I prefer you second way, but I have strange error: original is undefined

Comment: original parameter in your function signature is unnecessary

Comment: @Nawa it was a copy paste mistake

Comment: I think you forgot to return the value of the original function call.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the usage of the `new` keyword is completely incorrect. That will severely change the behaviour. `function` is an instance of `Function`, the "mothership" of all JavaScript functions.

When using the `new` keyword, the function will be immediately executed and the behaviour very different from what you expect. See **Section 13** of the **ECMA Language Specification** for more details on how to create function objects. Read it [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), at page 98.

Second, it is strongly discouraged to alter any native object `prototype`. It leads to the most tedious and painful bugs in human history. Anybody coming in after you to edit the code will spend a long time before figuring out where that alert originates from.

Keep those two actions separate, they are completely unrelated. Wrapping them up in a `prototype` function is very bad design, for the above reason any many more, such as:

1. Using `for in` loops. You will iterate through more properties that you should if you forget to use `hasOwnProperty`.
2. Yourself and other developers will have a hard time figuring out why random things are happing with a basic DOM Node remove operation occurs.(you will forget, happens to everybody).

Comment: These reasons are actually encouraging, the `for in` loop is ridiculous. I am not going to `for..in` anything other than plain objects, and if I am, it is not going to be DOM nodes. And the second reason is assuming a huge enterprise team of programmers. These 2 reasons apply to very few people, so that's why you are actually encouraging this :D

Answer (score 1):

I am going to be radical an just say no. While it may technically work on the browsers you care about and be the basis for prototype.js, you should never modify DOM objects, or their prototypes, like this.

There is a long post on the topic: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/ but the TL;DR is that these are "hosted objects" and modification to their behavior is not guaranteed. It may work today on browser x but there's no guarantee about browser y or even x tomorrow.

Answer (score -2):

Your implementation looks fine, except that you don't need to pass `original` as an argument there.

```
var original = node.removeChild;
node.removeChild = function(node) {
    alert('message');
    original(node);
}
```

Comment: this could cause a problem since the original method context is lost when you call `original(node);` see my answer

Comment: in FF I has error: Value does not implement interface Node. original(node); In chrome I has : Illegal invocation