# How to use prototype in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prototype, webpack, eslint

I would like enhance the `removeChild` property of the html in a reactJs based project, When i build it using webpack and eslint it showing `ReferenceError: Node is not defined`

This is the code i'm trying to use.

```
var original = Node.prototype.removeChild;
Node.prototype.removeChild = function(node) {

    try{
        original.apply(this, arguments);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: @zerkms Ahem... [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node#Remove_all_children_nested_within_a_node)  is an interface from which a number of DOM types inherit, and allows these various types to be treated (or tested) similarly.

Comment: I'm using this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148042/can-i-replace-s-standard-dom-functions-like-removechild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using isomorphic React? `Node` is tied to the `window` object which is non-existent on the server, so you'll get a reference error.

You can try something like this:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.Node) {
    var original = Node.prototype.removeChild;
    Node.prototype.removeChild = function(node) {
        original.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```